# How do I make aliases on codeigniter when using the join library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have tried to make **aliases** into the query so that it does not give the error of not unique tables.

as you can see i've placed *'AS'* with a new name after but it gives me an **error**. How am I doing this wrong?
this is what I have in my model:

```
<?php 
class Joins_model extends CI_Model{
    private $table = 'cm_proveedor, cm_compras, cm_valuacion, cm_valuacionr, cm_nomina, cm_empleado';
    function _construct(){
       parent::Model();
    }

    function get_reg($data){

        $this->db->select('
                            cm_valuacion.tipo_r AS valR,
                            cm_valuacion.mano_obra AS valM,
                            cm_valuacion.hojalateria AS valH,
                            cm_valuacion.pintura AS valP,
                            cm_valuacion.mecanica AS valMec,
                            cm_valuacion.refaccion AS valRef,
                            cm_valuacion.shojalateria AS valSH,
                            cm_valuacion.tipo AS valT,
                            cm_valuacion.spintura AS valSP,
                            cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria AS valCH,
                            cm_valuacion.smecanica AS valSM,
                            cm_valuacion.costoPintura AS valCP,
                            cm_valuacion.costoMecanica AS valCM,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria AS valPH,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_pintura AS valPP,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica AS valPM,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria AS valPH,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_pintura AS valPPin,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica AS valPMec,
                            cm_compras.precio,
                            cm_proveedor.nombre,
                            cm_nomina.nomina,
                            cm_empleado.nombre,
                            cm_nomina.id_nomina_gral
                            ',FALSE);

        $this->db->from('cm_valuacion');
        $this->db->join('cm_valuacionr','cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro');
        $this->db->join('cm_compras','cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro = cm_compras.id_siniestro');
        $this->db->join('cm_proveedor','cm_proveedor.id = cm_compras.id_proveedor');
        $this->db->join('cm_nomina','cm_nomina.id_siniestro = cm_compras.id_siniestro');
        $this->db->join('cm_empleado','cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id');
        $this->db->join('cm_nomina_gral','cm_nomina.id_nomina_gral = cm_nomina_gral.id');
        $this->db->where('cm_valuacion.id_siniestro',$data);
        //$this->db->order_by('id','asc');
        $this->db->distinct();
        return $this->db->get($this->table);
    }


}
?>
```

the error that I get is:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1066
>   Not unique table/alias: 'cm_valuacion'
>   SELECT DISTINCT cm_valuacion.tipo_r AS valR, cm_valuacion.mano_obra AS valM, cm_valuacion.hojalateria AS valH, cm_valuacion.pintura AS valP, cm_valuacion.mecanica AS valMec, cm_valuacion.refaccion AS valRef, cm_valuacion.shojalateria AS valSH, cm_valuacion.tipo AS valT, cm_valuacion.spintura AS valSP, cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria AS valCH, cm_valuacion.smecanica AS valSM, cm_valuacion.costoPintura AS valCP, cm_valuacion.costoMecanica AS valCM, cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria AS valPH, cm_valuacion.pv_pintura AS valPP, cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica AS valPM, cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria AS valPH, cm_valuacion.pc_pintura AS valPPin, cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica AS valPMec, cm_compras.precio, cm_proveedor.nombre, cm_nomina.nomina, cm_empleado.nombre, cm_nomina.id_nomina_gral FROM (`cm_valuacion`, `cm_proveedor`, `cm_compras`, `cm_valuacion`, `cm_valuacionr`, `cm_nomina`, `cm_empleado`) JOIN `cm_valuacionr` ON `cm_valuacionr`.`id_siniestro` = `cm_valuacion`.`id_siniestro` JOIN `cm_compras` ON `cm_valuacionr`.`id_siniestro` = `cm_compras`.`id_siniestro` JOIN `cm_proveedor` ON `cm_proveedor`.`id` = `cm_compras`.`id_proveedor` JOIN `cm_nomina` ON `cm_nomina`.`id_siniestro` = `cm_compras`.`id_siniestro` JOIN `cm_empleado` ON `cm_nomina`.`id_empleado` = `cm_empleado`.`id` JOIN `cm_nomina_gral` ON `cm_nomina`.`id_nomina_gral` = `cm_nomina_gral`.`id` WHERE `cm_valuacion`.`id_siniestro` = '6489'
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\index\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your JOIN clause. When you're joining the same table multiple times you have to assign an alias to the table name. When a table is joined multiple times, SQL doesn't know which table to refer to.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (cm_valuacion, cm_proveedor, cm_compras, cm_valuacion,
 cm_valuacionr, cm_nomina, cm_empleado) 
JOIN cm_valuacionr **valnr** ON **valnr**.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro
```

Comment: This is not ActiveRecord, which the OP clearly wishes to use.